# Reading matrices of large dimensions from GEdit

Tags: python, gedit

I am trying to read matrices from GEdit to an array in python. However, since the dimension of each matrix is 50x50, GEdit formats the output of the matrix for easy reading by human but I find it a bit complex to read using python.

This is a snippet of what I have in file, a 2x10 matrix

```
[array([ 0.81784824,  0.01441009, -0.00296465, -0.007367  , -0.00423666,
   -0.00982937,  0.00410125,  0.01136311,  0.03110279, -0.00865777]), array([  1.21658562e-02,   7.99373034e-01,   1.90868112e-02,
     7.45063105e-05,   8.84637998e-03,   6.89665233e-03,
    -1.57433517e-02,   2.81822951e-02,   1.06842757e-02,
     2.00615611e-02])]
```

This is the code I tried to read in the matrix

```
    for line in open('textfile.txt', 'r'):
        Mat = [eval(val) for val in line.split('\t')]
```

This reads only the first line in Gedit, thus

```
[array([ 0.81784824,  0.01441009, -0.00296465, -0.007367  , -0.00423666,
```

evaluating to a Syntax Error